# Connect rails app to a database running in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a postgresql db running on Docker, screenshot:[image]

I want to connect my rails app to this db.

I configure my database.yml like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: host.docker.internal
  port: 5432
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
  myproject git:(main) ✗ rake db:create
could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Couldn't create 'myprojecto_development' database. Please check your configuration.
```

What do I have wrong?
Do I need to create the docker-componse.yml and Dockerfile?

Comment: What OS?
Really, run the database in another container.  Call it 'db'.  Connect to 'db'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the name of PG container to the host property from the database.yml file.